# Post request Manytomany field DRF with postman

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, postman

Objective: Creating a new entry in database from Postman using the "POST".

I am trying to send the data from Postman and I am using nested serializing. I have changed the create method i have shared the snippet below. Also, I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276326/drf-post-to-manytomany-field) but it did not work. Can someone please point out the mistake I am making?

When I am trying to post as form-data the error is `{"magazine":["This field is required."]}`.
When I am trying to post it as raw data the error is `Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use magazine.set() instead.`

Here is my models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey('authors.Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    magazine = models.ManyToManyField('articles.Magazine')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Magazine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my serializers:

```
class MagazineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Magazine
        fields = '__all__'

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    magazine = MagazineSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'author',
            'magazine',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        allmags = []
        magazine = validated_data.pop('magazine')
        for i in magazine:
            if Magazine.objects.get(id=magazine["id"]).exists():
                mags = Magazine.objects.get(id=magazine["id"])
                allmags.append(mags)
            else:
                return Response({"Error":  "No such magazine exists"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            
        validated_data['author'] = self.context['request'].user
        validated_data['magazine'] = allmags
        return Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Here is my view:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class MagazineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Magazine.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MagazineSerializer

    serializer_action_class = {
        'get_articles': MagazineSerializer,
    }

    @action(detail=True, url_path='articles', url_name='articles')
    def get_articles(self, request, pk=None):
        articles = Article.objects.filter(magazine=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

This is how I tried sending data as raw:

```
{
    "title": "New Post form Postman",
    "content": "Postman content new",
    "magazine": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "The Times",
            "title": "All News"
        }
    ]
}
```

[This is how I posted as form-data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFfSH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, can you please clarify whether you wish to also create new `Magazine` objects from the nested serializer or do you want the user to only be able to create `Article` for existing magazines (it seems like the 2nd since you are calling `.exists()`) ?

#### 1st case:

If you were going for the 1st case, where you wish to also create new magazines within the same `POST` request, I'd recommend using the [drf-writeable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) package.

#### 2nd case:

For this as well, you should use the [drf-writeable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) package. Or, you can use this *hack* instead:

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Article, Magazine

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True, many=False)
    magazines = MagazineSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    # accept list of PKs
    magazines_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, write_only=True, queryset=Magazine.objects.all()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'author',
            'magazines',
            'magazines_ids',
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        magazines = validated_data.pop("magazines_ids", None)
        validated_data["author"] = self.context["request"].user
        article = Article.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if magazines:
            article.magazine.set(magazines)

        return article
```

Now your `POST` request `JSON` body should look like:

```json
{
    "title": "New Post form Postman",
    "content": "Postman content new",
    "magazines_ids": [1]
}
```

Where `magazines` parameter takes list of primary keys.

---

#### Bonus

Also, just out of my curiosity, are you sure you want to use a `ManytoManyField` ? I would assume that an `Article` can only belong to a *single* `Magazine` for which you should be using `ForeignKey`such as:

```py
magazine = models.ForeignKey("articles.Magazine", related_name="articles")
```

and then in your "action", you can make this change:

```py
@action(detail=True, url_path='articles', url_name='articles')
def get_articles(self, request, pk=None):
    articles = self.get_object().articles
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to achieve the 2nd case as you said, and I did try out doing it like this but I keep on getting the error `"Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.".` I also tried passing in the whole object but it does not work.

Comment: Also I tried out your solution and I get `AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'magazine_set'`

Comment: Actually, what I am doing is quite the opposite, I am trying to create articles and map it to multiple magazines i.e: An article can be published in many magazine, hence the ManytoMany field.

Comment: I just greatly improved my answer and made it short too. It should work now.

Comment: Tried this out as well but i get `AssertionError: The field 'magazines_ids' was declared on serializer ArticleSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.`

Comment: The "'magazines_ids" is missing from the `ArticleSerializer.Meta.fields`. Added it and updated my answer. I am sorry about this, I don't have a python environment available at this exact moment or I would have tested the code myself.

Comment: Please consider marking it "accepted" if it worked for you after the latest changes. :)

Comment: I tried it addin it but it shows, `"magazines_ids : "This field is required."`

Comment: Please see my answer carefully. I have also written an example request body.

Comment: Sorry about not passing the correct params, it works fine but now I can see the data does not show the nested serializing. I do not see any magazines details.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand. _When_ exactly you are not seeing the magazines details >

Comment: Please change the field `magazines` to `magazine` and everything works fine now. As I am using `magazine` in my models I was getting some kind of error.